# mmap and page alignment of data - does this increase performance?

Tags: c++, c, mmap

Is there any benefit to aligning my data in an mmap()ed file? i.e if data for an object to be read is offset with a multiple of the OS'es page size from the start of the file (or mmap?).

Would this result in faster read performance because less page faults are generated and the OS doesn't have to swap data in and out. How does this work?

Comment: If you're only reading a few records selected sparsely through the file then I suppose it's only one page per record instead of between 1 and 2. If you read a significant proportion of the file, then all the padding is wasted data that gets paged in. So as (almost) always with performance questions the answer is "It depends. You should test it instead of asking for idle speculation from people who don't have enough information" ;-)

Comment: Depends on quite a few factors. What's the access pattern? The typical page size can contain quite a few objects (unless they are very large), the overhead for hitting one extra page could be insignificant. Why are you even worried about that? Did you measure something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading around I have the answer.

If a small piece of data will cross the boundary of a page, it's probably better to align it with the next page as the OS loads data from the disk pages at a time.